# Reporting Services 2005 - Parameter reliant on cascading parameters

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

Good day

I have the following:

In a SSRS 2005 report I have three report parameters: FinancialPeriodType ("Month" or "Week" in  a DropDownList), FinancialPeriod (cascading DropDownList populated depending on first selection) and another parameter, OpeningBalance, of type float.

The first two parameters are cascading i.e. the first parameter is used by the query populating the second's available values. This works fine.

What I'm attemping to do is default the value of OpeningBalance to a value from a dataset populated by a stored procedure which takes in the first two parameters.
However as soon as I select a value for the first parameter, I get the following error:

An error occurred during report processing. The value for the report parameter 'OpeningBalance' is not valid for its type.'

I've tried setting the default of the second parameter to be a meaningful default (something like 200901) as well as defaulting the second parameter in the SQL store procedure with no affect.
Using SQL Profiler I've noticed that selecting a value for the first parameter doesn't even execute the SQL used to obtain available values for the second parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after much to-ing and fro-ing it appears RS doesn't like the fact that the parameter OpeningBalance is a float. Changing it to a string and then casting as necessary solved the problem.